# Improve quality of text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this message that I'm displaying on my app. I want to improve the text.

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

This is how I want it to look (Copied from Snapchat):

[image]

This is how my CSS looks now:

```
#footerNoInternet {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #e80c0c;
    border-color: #e80c0c;
    color: white;
}
```

Where #footerNoInternet is:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footerNoInternet" hidden>
    <p>No internet connection.</p>
</div>
```

How can I do this using CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try messing with text antialiasing; also you need some padding.

Used a larger font for the better demonstration; `text-align:center;` because in your image the text looks center-aligned. `margin: 0;` for removing margins.

As for the gradient, I went to the gradient link (at bottom) and just made a quick preset, then pasted CSS inside of snippet.

```css
#footerNoInternet {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #e80c0c;
  border-color: #e80c0c;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#8c0237+0,ad0011+3,e80435+100 */
background: #8c0237; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8c0237 0%, #ad0011 3%, #e80435 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c0237 0%,#ad0011 3%,#e80435 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8c0237 0%,#ad0011 3%,#e80435 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8c0237', endColorstr='#e80435',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#footerNoInternet > p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footerNoInternet">
  <p>No internet connection.</p>
</div>
```

[Recommend to read this Interesting Article](https://maximilianhoffmann.com/posts/better-font-rendering-on-osx)

[Gradients Site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fse4pcpx/)
i think you need you need to play with gradient and [Gradient tool](http://gradientfinder.com/) to convert image to gradient i think you need to play with font

```
#footerNoInternet {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #e80c0c;
    color: white;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(185, 57, 58) 0%, rgb(219, 71, 71) 61%, rgb(219, 71, 71) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to CY5's answer this is what I modified:

I changed `font-size` to `1em`, `color` to `rgb(244,244,244)` and I add `font family: sans-serif`.

It looks pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjr8ack0/).